# Provide action for button in the xib file using swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xib

PROVIDED: I have a button in my xib[image]
The swift file associated with this is also attached.

ISSUE: this cell has a button that need to display a ViewController on the button click. This cell is attached to the table view in another ViewController. I want to implement an action on the button "BOOK" so as on clicking the new view controller should open. i am not able to do this can any one suggest me something that i should do?

CODE:

```
import UIKit

class HotelBookingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var BookbtnOutlet: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        BookbtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func bookbtn1(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: call this `bookbtn1` one in your UIviewcontroller,

Comment: in your VC , in cellforrowatindex method add target on button

Comment: can you show the code `cellforrowatindex`

Comment: public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5;
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! BookHotellCell
    
           return cell
    }
@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the following code in tableviewcell class

```
/*
@IBAction func bookbtn1(_ sender: Any) {

} */
```

and add into your UIviewcontroller   cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell. BookbtnOutlet.tag = indexpath.row
cell. BookbtnOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. bookbtn1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside);
```

And anywhere in the same UIVeiwController define the function as below

```
func bookbtn1(_ sender : UIButton){
// call your segue code here
}
```

Comment: that's a spaghetti code :) although, this solution will definitely work

Comment: @SabaZehra - where you struck , would you need help related to this

Comment: can i get your mail id? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: But if I have two buttons this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions it to create a protocol for this:

```
protocol HotelBookingCellDelegate: class {
     // you can add parameters if you want to pass. something to controller
     func bookingCellBookButtonTouched()  
}
```

then is you cell class

```
class HotelBookingCell: UITableViewCell {
     // add a propery
     public weak var delegate: HotelBookingCellDelegate?

     @IBAction func bookbtn1(_ sender: Any) {
          delegate?.bookingCellBookButtonTouched()
     }
}
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.delegate = self
```

after that in you controller where you signed for this protocol, implement it

```
extension YourViewController: HotelBookingCellDelegate {
    func bookingCellBookButtonTouched() {
      // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a delegate protocol in the cell class and then set the delegate equal to viewcontroller where tablview cell will show up. Then on click the delegate function will be called and you will get the action the view controller where you can push or pop a view controller or any other action you want.

Sample code - Cell Class

```
protocol ButtonDelegate {
    func buttonClicked()
}

weak var delegate : ButtonDelegate?
@IBAction func bookbtn1(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.buttonClicked()
}
```

Now in View Controller conform to the protocol - "ButtonDelegate", set

```
cell.delegate = self
```

and then implement the method "buttonClicked()"

You will get the action in buttonClicked() when button is clicked.

Comment: Thankx will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solution here

1) You can add target for this button in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** like below code

cell.bookbtn1.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.bookbtn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. bookbtn1(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

2) another solution is in your main view controller you can add Notification center observer in **viewDidLoad** like this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.bookbtn1ClickedFromCell), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: BUTTON_CLICK), object: nil)
```

and implement method and navigate in another view controller from this method

```
func bookbtn1ClickedFromCell()
{
    //navigate to another vc
}
```

and in action method that you implemented in UITableViewCell file post this notification like this

```
@IBAction func bookbtn1(_ sender: Any) {

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: BUTTON_CLICK), object: self)
}
```

so it will called bookbtn1ClickedFromCell in your main view controller from this you can navigate to another view controller

you should remove observer in **viewWillDisappear** or in **deinit** method

```
 deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

**or**

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

}

Comment: add remove observer also on viewdisappear also

Comment: yes right need to remove observer in viewWillDisappear or you can also remove observer in **deinit**